# Forces acting on a cylinder

Tags: circles, classical-mechanics

In some amusement parks there is a ride which is effectively a hallow cylinder which can rotate about its vertical axis. The riders stand on horizontal base of the cylinder and in contact with the curved surface of the cylinder. When the angular speed reaches a certain value the floor is dropped but the riders remain in contact with the curved surface of the cylinder. The radius of the cylinder is **2.5m**, and the speed of rotation is **30 revolutions per minute**.

How do I draw the forces acting on this cylinder if people are modelled as a particle?

And how do I find the smallest possible coefficient of friction between the rider and the cylinder surface so that the ride works effectively?

I found the velocity but where do I go from here?

Comment: I think you'd do better with this question on the physics stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega$ be the angular speed so$$\omega=\frac{30\times2\pi}{60}$$ radians per second

Draw the normal reaction $N$ horizontally in the same direction as the acceleration $r\omega^2$. The limiting friction is $\mu N$ acting vertically upwards, and the weight is $mg$ vertically downwards.

So you then have $$\mu N=mg$$ and $$N=mr\omega^2$$

So you can solve to get $\mu$

Comment: Why the limiting friction μN is acting vertically upwards?

Comment: Because the passenger is on the point of slipping downwards if the surface is too smooth

Comment: so the friction is acting in the opposite way to the motion, I got it. Do you know what needs to be changed in the terms of the question in order to make the limiting friction point vertically downwards?

Comment: That's not possible. Since the wall is vertical there is no possibility that the passennger would be about to slip upwards. That could only happen if the wall was sloping backwards, then at high speeds, the passenger could be on the point of slipping upwards, so the limiting friction would then be down the slope.

Comment: This answered my questions greatly and gave me a better understanding of why your solution looks like this. Kindly thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Glad to be of help.